# How to write type adapter for GSON to send stream?

Tags: json, adapter, gson

One of the fields of my class is filename.
For serialization i'm going to write [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) type adapter (implements `JsonSerializer<MyClass>`) which should send file stream.

The problem is that i don't want it to read all file data (stream) and hold it as string in the memory as memory size is limited (it's mobile device) and i have to send some another fields (`filename` f.e. below), so json should look like:

```
data:
{
    filename:"filename.png"
    filedata:"(base64 file data stream here)"
}
```

What is the best way to send file data in network as a field in this case?

PS. Network sending is done by Apache Http Client if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's not good architectural solution to mix json and large binary data within one request body. One can use http Multipart instead:

```
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    request.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    // body
    try {
        multipartEntity.addPart("json", new StringBody(body, "application/json", Charset.forName("utf-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new ResourceLoadingException(e);
    }

    // files
    for (int i=0; i<filespaths.size(); i++) {
        String eachFilePath = filespaths.get(i);
        File file = new File(eachFilePath);
        multipartEntity.addPart("file" + String.valueOf(i), new FileBody(file));
    }
```

What about mobile devices Android does not support Multipart bodies but you can add support for it easily (if using Maven or Gradle):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```